# How to avoid java.net.URISyntaxException in URL.toURI()

Tags: java, url, uri

In a particular program, I am passed a `file:` URL and I need to convert it to a `URI` object.  Using the `toURI` method will throw a `java.net.URISyntaxException` if there are spaces or any other invalid characters in the URL.

For example:

```
URL url = Platform.getInstallURL();  // file:/Applications/Program
System.out.println(url.toURI());  // prints file:/Applications/Program

URL url = Platform.getConfigurationURL();  // file:/Users/Andrew Eisenberg
System.out.println(url.toURI());  // throws java.net.URISyntaxException because of the space
```

What is the best way of performing this conversion so that all special characters are handled?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I guess the best way would be to remove deprecated `File.toURL()` which is usually responsible for producing these incorrect URLs.

If you can't do it, something like this may help:

```
public static URI fixFileURL(URL u) {
    if (!"file".equals(u.getProtocol())) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    return new File(u.getFile()).toURI();
}
```

Comment: This looks pretty good to me.  I tried out a few variants and it is working.  I'm just going to do a little more testing before I accept.

Comment: Thanks axtavt.  This is what I am using now.  It seems to handle all kinds of odd file names and encodes only the special chars, while keeping slashes.

Comment: Warning: this method should not be used if the URL represents a "correct" with-escaped-spaces URL (eg: "/C:/Program%20Files"), as it would return the raw "C:/Program%20Files" file.

Answer (score 4):

I've had the same problem. The best solution in my opinion is to use the overloaded constructor for the URI object and fill it with the getters of the URL object. This way the URI constructor handles the path-url-encoding itself and other parts (like the slashes in after the protocol "http://") will not be touched.

```
uri = new URI(url.getProtocol(), url.getAuthority(), url.getHost(), url.getPort(), url.getPath(), url.getQuery(), url.getRef());
```

Fields that should not be set could be filled with null.

Comment: `url.getAuthority()` should be replaced with `url.getUserInfo()` in your call, i.e., it should be `new URI(url.getProtocol(), url.getUserInfo(), url.getHost(), url.getPort(), url.getPath(), url.getQuery(), url.getRef());`. Other than that as far as I can tell your answer is correct, thank you :)

Comment: Update: this doesn't work with `mailto:username@example.com?subject=Topic` doesn't work (produces a `java.net.URISyntaxException: Relative path in absolute URI: mailto://username@example.com?subject=Topic`) because `URI.checkPath` method, invoked from the constructor, expects a `/` after the protocol (`mailto`) if the path (`username@example.com`) isn't null. However, `new URL("mailto:username@example.com?subject=Topic").toURI()` does work in this case.

Answer (score 0):

This is **untested** but you could, effectively, do this:

```
URL url = Platform.getConfigurationURL();  // file:/Users/Andrew Eisenberg
System.out.println(new URI(URLEncoder.encode(url.toString(), "UTF-8")));
```

Alternatively, you could do this:

```
System.out.println(new URI(url.toString().replace(" ", "%20")));
```

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't work since it wants to encode everything.  It will return something like: "file%3A%2FUsers%2FAndrew+Eisenberg".  I need something like: "file:/Users/Andrew%20Eisenberg"  (or whatever the encoding is for a space).

Comment: Sorry...pressed enter too fast :)

Comment: The .replace() won't work since I need to handle any path that is valid on the current OS, so on Unix variants, this would include just about any ascii character